# Changing HTML Content & Assigning Events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-applications

I have a div which has a form for logging in. Below the textfields, I have a link "Forgot Password":

```
<div id = "loginpanel" class="left_block">
                <h2>Login</h2>
                <p>Enter your login details</p>
                <form name = "loginform" action = "http://dev.speechlink.co.uk/David/get_login.php" method = "post">
                   <input id = "emailtxt" name = "username" type="text" size="25" placeHolder = "E-mail"/> 
                   <input id = "passwordtxt" name = "password" type="password" size="25" placeHolder = "Password"/>                                    
                </form>
                <p id= "forgot">Forgot password? Click <a id = "forgot" href = "">here</a></p>
                <a id = "signin" href = "http://www.url.com/home.php"> Sign In</a>
</div>
```

Rather than taking the user to a new page, I want to overwrite the login panel with the required form. I do this using the following jQuery:

```
$("#forgot").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#loginpanel").html("<h2>Forgot Login Details</h2> <p>Enter your registered e-mail address</p><form name = \"forgotlogin\" action = \"http://dev.speechlink.co.uk/David/forgot_login.php\" method = \"post\"><input id = \"forgotdetails\" name = \"forgotdetails\" type=\"text\" size=\"25\" placeHolder = \"E-mail\"/></form><p id= \"back\">Back To <a id = \"backbtn\" href = \"\">Login</a></p><a id = \"submit\" href = \"\">Submit</a>");
});
```

This not only seems clunky and very unreadable, it doesn't allow me to assign click functions to the links that are generated in the above event handler (e.g. backbtn and submit). What is a better way of achieving the above?

Comment: If you want something less clunky and more readable you can go with an onclick event on the link. Also be sure to change the href to # and add a return false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do it depending on whether you are happy to have your site depend on JavaScript or if you just want to use the JavaScript and dynamic content for progressive enhancement of a form that would work even for users with JavaScript turned off.

Ajax has already been suggested and is a reasonable option.

Another way is to include the forgotten login details markup in a second div that is initially hidden:

```
<div id="forgottenLogin" style="display:none;">
   <h2>Forgot Login Details</h2>
   etc.
</div>
```

Then in your JavaScript you hide the standard login div and show the forgotten details one. I tend to prefer that to creating all the HTML dynamically.

Having said that, you should be able to attach events to the HTML you are creating dynamically. Is there some specific problem you're having getting that to work?

Regarding your existing code being unreadable, you can pretty it up without changing the functionality at all if you add a few line breaks and wrap the string in single quotes so that you don't need to escape all of the double quotes. Something like this:

```
$("#loginpanel").html(
     '<h2>Forgot Login Details</h2>'
   + '<p>Enter your registered e-mail address</p>'
   + '<form name="forgotlogin" method="post"'
   + ' action="http://dev.speechlink.co.uk/David/forgot_login.php">'
   + '<input id="forgotdetails" name="forgotdetails" type="text" size="25"'
   + ' placeHolder="E-mail"/>'
   + '</form>'
   + ' etc. '
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery's `.load()` method to show the content via ajax. http://api.jquery.com/load/
Save the password form as a separate html file and load it into the #loginpanel on click.

eg.

```
$("#forgot").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#loginpanel').load('ajax/password-form.html #password-form', function(response, status, xhr){
        if (status == "success") {
            alert("success");
        }
        // add click events here
    });
});
```